# Read data from text file as list array

Tags: c#

I want to read data from file as list array but when i implement this code i found error in result . 
this is my code and the data in text file is the same data in double []x

```
try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"E:\TestFile.txt"))
            {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    data += line + " ";
            }
            //   Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        double[] x = new double[100];
        int ind = 0;
        double num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            num *= 10;
            num += data[i] - '0';
            if (data[i] == ' ')
            {
                x[ind++] = num;
                num = 0;
            }
        }
        //  double[] x = { 9, 3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 8, 1, 7, 0, 6, 4, 4, 5 };
```

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: Ah, I see - number `5` should not present in result?

Comment: what is your input and expected output?

Comment: Instead of using StreamReader, you can just use `File.ReadAllLines()`

Comment: what is the type of variable `data`?

Comment: this code for DTW algorithm and this is code for it's implement [http://ideone.com/nE5TWn] and this is my main code [http://ideone.com/y5IRLH]

Comment: your URL's are broken

Comment: this is code for main [main](http://ideone.com/mVHOwY)
and this for [DTW](http://ideone.com/saspg7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing exactly the content of your text file it's pretty much a guess game but if it is just numbers separated by spaces or new lines this should do :

```
double[] x =
    // Read all lines inside an IEnumerable<string>
    File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\TestFile.txt")
    // Create a single string concatenating all lines with a space between them
    .Aggregate("", (current, newLine) => current + " " + newLine)
    // Create an array with the values in the string that were separated by spaces
    .Split(' ')
    // Remove all the empty values that can be due to multiple spaces
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    // Convert each string value into a double (Returning an IEnumerable<double>)
    .Select(s => double.Parse(s))
    // Convert the IEnumerable<double> to an array
    .ToArray();
```